# A mouse connected to a USB 1 port vs USB 2.0 port

Tags: usb, mouse

I need more USB ports but my hub is USB 1.0. If I connect my mouse to it, is there any drop in performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using USB 1.1 rather than USB 1.0, unless your hub is *really* old - [USB 1.0 was short lived and hugely uncommon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.0)

Practically there i would think that there shouldn't be much difference - the data transfer for the average mouse should be significantly less than the 12 MBit/s maximum speed of USB 1.1 or even the fallback 1.5 MBit/s speed of low speed USB  (though no one really seems to have hard data on that), and the extra performance of USB 2.0 is really cause USB started being used for mass storage (which earlier USB versions weren't very good at, they were supposed to be a versatile way to plug in peripherals primarily).

Now, if you have some fancy, USB 2.0 requiring all singing all dancing supermouse, maybe *JUST MAYBE* it might not like being plugged into USB 1.1 hub, and act up, but its hard to tell. If you DID have such a mouse, get a better hub

ALl that said this is one of those things that has too many variables to give a definitive answer, so i suggest spending the 30 seconds or so actually trying it.

Comment: ^agree.  never saw a mouse that needed more speed than 1.1, or that acted so different under the new ports vrses the old ones, when they made that change. Other things desperatly needed the speed.

Comment: second the motion.. a standard usb mouse will not loose performance on USB1.0 - It just sends PS/2 Emulated data, which is RS-323(bus mouse) ,which ran at 9600kb. Newer gaming mice use extra data and might need faster ports, just as answer suggests.

Comment: Actually, i believe everything modern would use the standard USB HID class. I just don't think they need much bandwith compared to lots of other stuff

Comment: There's probably not much performance difference (for a mouse) between using a USB 1.x hub vs USB 2 hub.  However, there's a non-trivial difference between *any* hub vs direct connection to a root port.